# Mockito/PowerMock - possible to mock new MyClass()?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

```
public void doSomething(){
    //...
    HibernateCursorItemReader<Object[]> reader = new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();
    //...
}
```

how to mock reader, or make new `HibernateCursorItemReader<>()` return a mock Object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock constructor with PowerMockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110804/how-to-mock-constructor-with-powermockito)

Comment: There's no way to access reader. Is it possible to make it at least an argument to doSomething to be possible to inject it?

Comment: You can use powermock like in the linked potential duplicate to return a completly different object or you can also use `Mockito.spy(reader)`, which allows you to mock certain methods

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();` with a method and mock it instead, e.g.:

```
 HibernateCursorItemReader<Object[]> getReader() {
      return new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();
 }

 public void doSomething(){
     //...
     HibernateCursorItemReader<Object[]> reader = getReader(); // use method invocation to get a reader
     //...
 }
```

Now, when you want to mock `reader`, mock `getReader()` method instead and return whatever you want:

```
MyObject object = ...; //your original object

MyObject spyObject = Mockito.spy(object);
Mockito.doReturn(/*your value*/).when(spyObject).getReader();
```